# Android Studio Cache Invalidation

Tags: java, android

What is meant by android cache invalidation and what is the benefit of it?

How does the memory locations and references changes after invalidation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android studio caches a lot of files, including symbolic references and mainly android property reflections. when you use `view.findViewByid()` it internal uses reflections to fetch the view matched by id. sometimes this symbolic link becomes corrupted and loses the connection. And sometimes that is why sometimes you see that red color around the `R keyword`. invalidate resets and re-links all files, clearing the built up cache.

Comment: Thanks I understand it now

Comment: this means android does automatically delete for you